# Singular word request: Word that means 'to attempt to fit in/be as a normal person would, though failing'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a writer, and for this story, all chapter titles will be one word long. This is the first chapter, and I'm looking for a word that means something in the nature of "attempting to fit in" or the sort.

I'll give you a little insight:

It's about a girl who, a week before, had run into a man who had threatened her and wanted her to be his girlfriend. This occurs in the prologue. She doesn't want this to get in the way of her normal life, but she's anti social anyway. So she decides to go to the beach, just to find a plane flying around with a banner that reads 'This is your last warning, my little bird.' Or something of the sort. I only have a rough draft of it so far. It's hard to fit in with a banner flying over your head and threatening you.

It doesn't have to fit exactly. But anything even remotely close to my description is appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I'm sorry I was a bit unclear. As for a sentence, well, I don't particularly intend to use the word in a sentence, but rather as a standalone word to describe the main character in this chapter, as described above. I kind of feel that an adjective would fit best, but I don't really mind if it is or is not. This said, I can't really give a solid sentence that I would use, unless you count an average adjective sentence such as: 'I saw the [blank] woman walking around,' or something like that for nouns/verbs/advervs.

Comment: If you need a single word to capture the concept, **normalcy** might apply (a normal condition or situation).

Comment: You want a single word for a attempting and failing? Please state clearly how you would use the word in a sentence.

Comment: It's not a verb for 'an attempt to fit' but a 'noun' for such a person **who tries to fit in a group, but fails** - [Misfit](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/misfit)

Comment: ....Alienation.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible words depending on which you feel is more the thrust.

For someone trying to fit in and failing (as in your question):  [tryhard](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tryhard)

Someone doesn't fit in with the group (more like your description):  [unassimilated](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unassimilated)

Answer (score 0):

The word thst arises for me is Misfit.

However given the circumstances you describe the guy is clearly a dick and she should:

1. Stay as far away from him as possible
2. Immediately seek an AVO from the courts

Answer (score -1):

**'epic fail:'** (informal) [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epic-fail)
*you have been unsuccessful*!

> Word origin of 'epic fail!' from a message displayed in a Japanese
>   computer game after a player has failed to complete the game
>   successfully

**epic fail** (noun, Slang.) [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/epic-fail)

> 1. a spectacularly embarrassing or humorous mistake, humiliating situation, etc., that is subject to ridicule and given a greatly
>      exaggerated importance.
> 2. a person who fails in this way: He thought he was being funny and charming, but no, he was an epic fail.

Comment: −1  (1) Obviously not a single word. (2) There’s nothing about “epic fail” that relates to attempting to fit in. (3) There’s nothing about the question that suggests that “a spectacularly embarrassing or humorous mistake, humiliating situation, etc.” is an appropriate answer.